# How to read strings from a Scanner in a Java console application?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int employeeId, supervisorId;
        String name;
        System.out.println("Enter employee ID:");
        employeeId = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter employee name:");
        name = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Enter supervisor ID:");
        supervisorId = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

I got this exception while trying to enter a first name and last name.

```
Enter employee ID:
101
Enter employee name:
firstname lastname
Enter supervisor ID:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.controller.Menu.<init>(Menu.java:61)
    at com.tests.Employeetest.main(Employeetest.java:17)
```

but its working on if I only enter the first name.

```
Enter employee ID:
105
Enter employee name:
name
Enter supervisor ID:
501
```

What I want is to read the full string whether it is given as `name` or as `firstname lastname`. What's the problem here?

Comment: Change `scanner.next()` to `scanner.nextLine()`.

Comment: `sid=(scanner.nextInt());  `it expects an int and not a string, this is why it works with the `501`

Comment: Calling nextInt() was a problem as it didn't pick up the new line (when you hit enter). So, calling scanner.nextLine() after that does the work. See my answer and comment in code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int employeeId, supervisorId;
String name;
System.out.println("Enter employee ID:");
employeeId = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); //This is needed to pick up the new line
System.out.println("Enter employee name:");
name = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter supervisor ID:");
supervisorId = scanner.nextInt();
```

Calling `nextInt()` was a problem as it didn't pick up the new line (when you hit enter). So, calling `scanner.nextLine()` after that does the work.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use delimeter as new line. Till you press enter key you will be able to read it as string.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
System.out.println("Enter EmployeeName:");
                 ename=(scanner.next());
```

with:

```
System.out.println("Enter EmployeeName:");
                 ename=(scanner.nextLine());
```

This is because next() grabs only the next token, and the space acts as a delimiter between the tokens. By this, I mean that the scanner reads the input: "firstname lastname" as two separate tokens. So in your example, ename would be set to firstname and the scanner is attempting to set the supervisorId to lastname

Comment: `scanner.nextLine(); //This is needed to pick up the new line ;
                                                              System.out.println("Enter EmployeeName:");
                ename=scanner.nextLine(); `

Answer (score 0):

You are entering a null value to nextInt, it will fail if you give a null value...

i have added a null check to the piece of code

Try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class MyClass
{
     public static void main(String args[]){

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                int eid,sid;
                String ename;
                System.out.println("Enter Employeeid:");
                     eid=(scanner.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Enter EmployeeName:");
                     ename=(scanner.next());
                System.out.println("Enter SupervisiorId:");
                    if(scanner.nextLine()!=null&&scanner.nextLine()!=""){//null check
                     sid=scanner.nextInt();
                     }//null check
        }
}
```