# How can I create "new" terminal parameters using Java?

Tags: java, terminal, command, line

I have an application that is opened by the terminal. It loads some data automatically and now I need to be able to use commands such as -new or -min or -help within the terminal with functionalities implemented in my Java code. So I need to define new parameters for my command line (which only work during the runtime of my apllication).

I tried to search it for several hours now but all I get are tips how to run java programs with my command line...
So I am pretty stuck right now and hope you can help me out.
I am thankfull for every answer.

Comment: Maybe have a look at scanner:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582362/how-do-i-get-user-input-when-i-run-my-jar-file-from-command-prompt

Comment: I had a look at the post you showed me there, but I can`t find a connection to my question. I want to know how I can define a new command line command which only works during the runtime of my application. It does not seem to have anythin to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

All the command line arguments for your program are passed to the `main` method in that method's only parameter, the string array (typically named `args`).

You can parse this array manually, or feed it to a library like [Getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/api/gnu/getopt/Getopt.html) to handle all of that for you.

Comment: I am not sure if I got this right. Would you mind showing me an example?

Comment: For now I think it could look like this: public class *** { public static void main (String[] args) { ..... }} And there you would put your parameters into the args?  How would that look like for parameters like --name, --min, --max? I just have no experience with giving parameters to my main method like that...