# Runtime error- java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

program to input 2d array using `Scanner` class but output shows:

```
Runtime error:
 NZEC
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Wocode.main(Main.java:9)
```

Code snippet:

```
import java.lang.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

     class Wocode {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
                int m=s.nextInt();
                int n=s.nextInt();
                int A[][] = new int[m][n];
                for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
                {
                  for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                    {
                     A[i][j]=s.nextInt();
                    }
                }     
    }
    }
```

Comment: what do you input? What do you expect the code to do when you do input anything other than an integer?

Comment: Please use `hasNextInt` before getting `nextInt`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `nextInt()` as it doesn't clean the line in the buffer. So, a better way to the user input is to use `s.nextLine()`. To take integer input do

```
Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine())
```

When you use `nextInt()` it takes the input but the line after the input is still there in the buffer and when the another `nextInt()` looks for the input you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to cricket_007. Need to check hasNext() method before calling s.next() as below.
<`if(s.hasNextInt()){
   A[i][j]= s.nextInt();
}`>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling hasNextInt, you should use a blocking readLine call and cast to an integer instead.

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few mistakes.

Here is a sequence, how to solve them:

- you have to say to a user what exactly the program expects as input
- validate if the user entered correct values
- parse entered values
- use that values

You didn't do some steps. Therefore, your solution isn't even executed.

Here is some code snippet, which fits all steps:

```
class Wocode {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter two numbers (separated by space): ");

        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String[] input = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            if (input.length == 2) {
                int firstNumber = Integer.valueOf(input[0]);
                int secondNumber = Integer.valueOf(input[1]);

                int arr[][] = new int[firstNumber][secondNumber];

                for (int rows = 0; rows < firstNumber; rows++) {
                    for (int columns = 0; columns < secondNumber; columns++) {
                        arr[rows][columns] = firstNumber + secondNumber;
                        System.out.print(String.format("%4s", arr[rows][columns]));
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("You have to enter two digits, separated by space!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Please enter two numbers (separated by space): 3 5
   8   8   8   8   8
   8   8   8   8   8
   8   8   8   8   8
```

***Useful links:***

- [How to read strings with scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691162/how-to-read-strings-from-a-scanner-in-a-java-console-application)
- [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)